# Memory Available for Activation Stack?

Tags: c++

What is the maximum amount of memory available for activation stack to store activation records? I've been reading about activation stack, and was wondering what would be its limit.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a feature of C++ as it depends on the specific operating system.

Comment: Thank You for answering!